# Scrape URLs from <cite> tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the URLs from Google using Requests and Beautiful Soup web scraping libraries.

```
for URL in soup.find_all('cite'):
    print(URL.text)
```

I was previously trying to get the URLs by searching for the links and then getting the href of the links but the problem with this method seems to be that these URLs are cached by Google, and when trying to access the URL the link is often broken.

I noticed that Google uses cite tags to hold the URLs. Whilst this works for the vast majority of URLs, sometimes there are other bits of text on the page also within cite tags.

Most of the tags have a class = "_Rm" or class = "Rm bc". How could I tell Beautiful Soup to search for tags with a class of substring "Rm"?

I understand there is probably a better way to do all of this. Is anyone aware of how I could do this / another method which will return the actual URL of websites?

This is the code that I had previously been using to get URLs

```
for URL in soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):

    print ("\n" + URL.text + "\n")

    print re.split(":(?=http)",URL["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))'''
```

Comment: I imagine it's loaded through JS, so beautifulsoup wont find it.

Comment: Use [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) instead of `requests`.

Comment: ah yes I think I will have to use selenium in order to scrape dynamically generated content. Thanks for the responses